# Assign default value to xsd attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-attribute

In a XSD document, is there a way to assign the value of a required attribute as a default value to another attribute?

```
<xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:token" use="required"/>
<xsd:attribute name="Display Name" type="xsd:token" use="optional" default="*Value of attribute Name*"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

No, default values cannot be computed, even in XSD 1.1. It would be very easy to achieve the desired effect using XSLT, however.